# Form of an Ajax request doesn't get submitted

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I load pictues and radio buttons with and Ajax request. After that i want to submit this radio buttons if i click on <%= sg.submit 'Confirm Step 1' %>. The submit works for all forms but not for the Ajax one`s. What is wrong?

Info: The Ajax content gets loaded to the div.

View - new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :site, :html => { :id => "form_all" }  do |sg| %>
  ...
  <%= sg.submit 'Confirm Step 1' %>
  <%= sg.text_field :subject %>
  ...

  <div id="pics_<%= deal.DealID %>">
  </div

  <%= link_to "Get pictures", {:action => "new", :format => :js }, :remote => true %> 
<% end %>
```

Controller - site_controller.rb

```
def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

JS - new.js.erb

```
$("#hidden_div").html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "hidden" ) %>');
var div_name = $("#hidden_field").val();
var substr = div_name.split('"');
$(substr[1]).html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "pic" ) %>');
```

JS - application.hs

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_all").submitWithAjax();
})
```

Partial - _pic.html.erb

```
<% @Pics.each do |pic| %>
  <a href="<%= pic.PublicServerURI %>" target="_blank"><%= image_tag(("#{pic.PublicServerURI}"), :size => "100x80") %></a>                                       
  <input value="<%= pic.PublicServerURI %>" id="site_pics" name="pics[DealID[<%= @DealID %>]]" type="radio">Use Deal with that Picture<br> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of ruby at all, but it is possible to post some of the real output? And you have not posted a single line of jquery...

Comment: Hey what do you mean with the real output? i dont have posted jquery because its working it loads the pictures and radio buttons. I will add more details!

Comment: real output means the html ruby spits out

Comment: Real output of form elements added

Comment: Please post the full code for the forms — I've a hunch…. (And how is this not a real question?)

Comment: We need the html the ruby-script produce. And how do you expect us to track down a (most likely) jQuery-related problem without a single line of javascript-code?

Comment: Sorry dudes i posted all code that could belong to the problem now!

Comment: Do you have submit button on form?
AFAIR, some browsers do not generate submit event, if there's no submit button.

Comment: I tryed <%= submit_tag "bla" %> but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t nest `form_for` to my knowledge since you can’t nest form tags. You also shouldn't use more than one submit button per form.

I would probably try something like

```
link_to "Get pictures", new_foo_path, :remote => true
```

replacing the content via the response.

Comment: And how do it works with the new_foo_path? Controller is named: site and action: new

Comment: You can assign them directly via `:controller => "site", :action => "new"`, but if you have defined your routes properly, you should be able to use `new_site_path` as well. Run `rake routes` to see which helpers are available and which routes are defined.

Comment: I used <%= button_to "Get pictures", :controller => "site", :action => "new", :remote => true %>  now instant of my second form_for but it don`t works for me, he reloads the page and don`t get the ajax.

Comment: Are you including rails.js? Are you getting any Javascript errors?

Comment: Okay thx for this one. I changed form_for to link_to for the Ajax call, but it don`t change the problem that the Ajax Forms can`t be submitted by the form_for :site do |sg|